# How can we merge .cdg and .mp3 file in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, mp4

I am trying to  merge **.cdg** file and **.mp3** file to make **.mp4** file with help of ffmpeg.

I am using following command:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp3 -i test.cdg -y  test.MP4
```

MP4 file was created only with mp3 audio file. cdg file contain is missing

Answer (score 3):

Little script I put together for this purpose (Batch-processing):

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                     

for filename in *.cdg; do
    ffmpeg -n -itsoffset 0.5 -i ./"$filename" -i ./"${filename/.cdg/.mp3}" -s 640x480 -c:a copy -r 15 -b:v 500k -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -map 0:0 -map 1:0 ../Transcoded/"${filename/.cdg/.mp4}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I have complied my ffmpeg from the source and every things works :)

```
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using latest windows version git-2017-12-22-e3b2c85

Put the cdg file first.  I had to increase the video to 1mbps.

```
ffmpeg -i test.cdg3 -i test.mp3 -b:v 1M -y test.MP4
```

Answer (score 0):

Many of these answers might be outdated with the latest versions of ffmpeg. They were not producing playable files in ffmpeg 6.0

After much experimentation, here is the resulting command I ended up with that does the job and has faster encode times:

`ffmpeg -i <mp3_file> -copyts -i <cdg_file> -filter:v fps=25 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`

Note the following additional parameters:

- `-copyts` fixes audio sync issues in certain configurations. *
- `-filter:v fps=25` limits the output to 25 frames per second. Otherwise ffmpeg was producing 300fps files, which is slower to encode and produces 12x larger files with virtually no quality difference.
- `-pix_fmt yuv420p` I noticed Raspberry pi (my host machine for the conversion) reported `Encoder requires yuv420p pixel format` and OSX was producing files not playable in Quicktime. By default, ffmpeg tries to pick the pixel format most closely matching the original source. However, this is not necessarily supported by the output codec. Forcing it to a known-supported format for mp4 fixed these issues for both.

*Source: [How to make ffmpeg respect the "start_time" variable when combining cdg and mp3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078498/how-to-make-ffmpeg-respect-the-start-time-variable-when-combining-cdg-and-mp3)