# How to make ffmpeg respect the "start_time" variable when combining cdg and mp3?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, mkv

I'm trying to combine two .cdg and .mp3 files because I want to make a single .mkv file out of them.

When I do it I get a .mkv file alright, but the audio is unfortunately not synced with the video.

So, I was wondering why this is? Apparently I must be missing a parameter on my command or something.

What I do is this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i song.cdg -i song.mp3 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy song.mkv
```

It works fine, but in this particular case the result is out of sync by ~1.2 seconds. This varies per song, from 0 to a couple of seconds.

However, if I do a ffprobe on the .cdg file I notice that this number is already present, as the "start_time" variable:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_format -show_streams song.cdg
...
start_time=1.186667
...
```

So, if I just use this number directly as this for the -itsoffset parameter:

```
ffmpeg -y -itsoffset 1.186667 -i song.cdg -i song.mp3 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy song.mkv
```

Then the video and audio is in perfect sync.

So, I am wondering - what parameter do I need to add to my command to have ffmpeg respect this variable?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to add the -copyts parameter and it solved my problem.

```
ffmpeg -copyts -y -i song.cdg -i song.mp3 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy song.mkv
```

---

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

> -copyts
> Do not process input timestamps, but keep their values without trying to sanitize them. In particular, do not remove the initial
> start time offset value.
>
> Note that, depending on the vsync option or on specific muxer
> processing (e.g. in case the format option avoid_negative_ts is
> enabled) the output timestamps may mismatch with the input timestamps
> even when this option is selected.

Comment: I had the same issue and this solved it too. BTW you can accept your own answer.